# How to start a Xamarin Android service at runtime?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to start an Android service for FCM that receives the device token. I don't want the user to register their device till they login and click on a button to allow notifications.

The FCM examples on Microsoft site all start the service automatically and which registers the device when the app starts.

My service that automatically starts - I **don't** want this service to start till the user clicks a button.

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" })]
public class FireBaseIdService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    public async override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var fcmToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Have you tried [stopping a service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent)) from your Froms.Android code?

Comment: Stopping doesn't seem to do anything. What I am trying to do it is not let it start at the beginning so I can control the start. I want to start it later. I just don't know how to tell it not to start yet.